# Jenkins/Hudson CLI API get the node that the script is running on using Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Hudson API in Jenkins written in groovy and i want to get the labels of the current slave that the script is running on. I know i can get the labels that were passed in but that's not what I want. I can get all the slaves using

hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves

but how do I know which one I am running on? once I have the node I can change the label using myslave.getAssignedLabels() but getting that node seems to be an issue. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getAssignedLabels` from [Node](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Node.html) class:

```
Computer.currentComputer().getNode().getAssignedLabels()
```